# Array not registering added ints

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a problem on leetcode ([Two Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/#/description)):

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such
>   that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
>   you may not use the same element twice.
>
> Example: Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].

I tried my own solution and the array always showed [0,0]. So I tried a solution that they had after several tweeks and that still showed [0,0] when I put it in and it was the highest ranked solution. Is it me or is it leetcode?

Original Solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] indices = new int[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < nums.length-1; j++)
            {
                if(target == (nums[i] + nums[j]))
                {
                  indices[0] = i+1;
                  indices[1] = j+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
}
```

Leetcode Solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] indices = new int[2];
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(target - nums[i]))
            {
                indices[1] = i + 1;
                indices[0] = map.get(target - nums[i]);
                return indices;
            }
            map.put(nums[i], i + 1);
        }
        return indices;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why neither of these will register ints in the indices array, it continually returns [0,0] for both solutions.

Comment: what's the code supposed to do? What problem is it solving?

Comment: You haven't provided sample input, so it's hard to know what's going on... please provide a [mcve] and explain what you *expect* to happen. (Ideally, step through it in a debugger, too... that may well help you work it out for yourself.)

Comment: Note that your condition of `j < nums.length-1` should probably be `j < nums.length`... at the moment your code is never using the last element of `nums`.

Comment: Why are you doing -1 after nums.length?

Answer (score 0):

1. In my understanding your innerloop must not start with i+1, cause you have to check each index in your array. only if the index of the inner and outer loop match, you should skip it, cause you won't add the index with itself.
2. you must loop your array to the end (so i removed the -1 in the for-statement)
3. why are you returning i+1 and j+1 if you found a match? (so i removed this)

see my code. maybe it will be more clear, what im trying to say :-)

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        int[] result = solution.twoSum(new int[] { 2, 7, 11, 15 }, 17);
        System.out.println(result[0] + "/" + result[1]);
    }

    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] indices = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    //do not use the same index for sum
                    continue;
                }
                if (target == (nums[i] + nums[j])) {
                    indices[0] = i;
                    indices[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to loop through combinations of two within an array can be done as follows:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<nums.length-1 ; i++)
    for(int j=i+1 ; j<nums.length ; j++)
        if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
            return new int[] {i, j};

return null; //in case there's no such case
```

Comment: Not a scalable solution. it is O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: If you want a solution with a smaller time complexity, then use some sort of a recursive algorithm, that looks similiar to efficient sorting algorithms